# Oracle sql query to find specific records

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table "`table_1`" with following columns:

```
table_id (PK-1) number,
table_id_2 (PK-2) varchar2(100),
table_code varchar2(15),
table_version varchar2(2)
```

I would like to find all `table_code`'s that have more than one unique `table_version` (1 and 2, suppose) value. This was my attempt, but I don't think it's correct.

```
SELECT table_code, table_version,COUNT(*) 
FROM table_1 
WHERE table_version IN (1,2) 
GROUP BY table_code,table_version 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: You are mixing two things together. What should the output include: (1) just the table_code when there is more than one version, and the count of versions, or (2) the table code AND table version, always more than one row with the same table code, AND for each table code, the count of versions?  Separately from this question: is it possible to have the same table_code with the same table_version more than once in the table? In that case do you want to count versions, or distinct versions? (Of course, if such duplicates are not possible, the question does not arise.)

Comment: I just want to see if there is a possibility of having multiple table_versions for a given table_code, and if so, list those table_code's.

Comment: Then it's exactly Gordon's answer. Just not sure about the IN condition, perhaps you don't need it either. Don't you want to find table codes with versions 2 and 4, for example? Why just 1 and 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close.  As written, it is mostly taking out `table_version` from the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT table_code, COUNT(*) 
FROM table_1 
WHERE table_version IN (1, 2) 
GROUP BY table_code
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

If you can have duplicates in the table, then you want `COUNT(DISTINCT)` for the condition instead:

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT table_code) = 2
```